# Angular 5 angular2gridster on IE11

Tags: angular, npm, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-11, gridster

So i'm working on a project which the main dashboard is using the angular2gridster and when a "heavy" widget(contains a list of 30 rows of data) is added and i drag a widget(not necessarily the "heavy" one the fps drops to like 10fps, if i had another "heavy" widget of the same kind, it goes to like 2fps).

My first approach was when i start to drag, to remove the data from the widget and on drop, restore it. It worked with one heavy widget, but with several on the dashboard, it returned to be problematic.
From my understanding, the grid detects changes only on drag start and drop, so why along the way of dragging the fps is so low as if it detects changes on every movement? (my own code has no change detection, i tried to make the change detection strategy to onPush and even detach the detector on drag start and re-attach it on drop with no luck).

I'm using angular 5, and the app is running on IE11(customers' limitations)- it is important to mention that on chrome the dragging is smooth even with said "heavy" widgets.
Hope you can shed some light for me or give me a lead on what i should try because i'm out of ideas..

Comment: Only description about the issue will not help much to understand it properly. If possible for you than share some sample code which we can directly run in IE 11 browser to check the issue. It can be helpful to us to understand the issue in better way. Because we don't know whether it caused by your own code, caused by Angular gridster or caused by IE 11. It also can be possible that IE meet with any limitation caused this issue or your application is too heavy and consuming lot of memory which downs the performance of IE.

Comment: I will try to find sample code i can put on but it will take time.. As i stated, in chrome this issue doesn't occur, so it has to be with IE- what can cause that?

Comment: If you provide sample than we can try to make a test with to find what caused it. without it we are not able to make any guess.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT take this example for instance- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2gridster-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts it's pretty much what i have just the widgets display a list of objects. on chrome it runs smoothly but on IE it lags..

Comment: I try to check your example with IE 11 browser and find that Stackblitz output window get hanged and there is no response. Other options of stackblitz also did not respond. It can be possible that issue caused by Stackblitz. I suggest you to provide feedback regarding this issue to stackblitz support and also try to report the issue here. https://recordnotfound.com/angular-gridster-ManifestWebDesign-24895/issues I did not found any way to fix this issue from IE side.